# Uploading images to Firebase Storage using firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I always have a hard time when I'm uploading images to my Firebase project using the `firebase-admin` package.

Here is what I get when I upload images as an admin user, using my app's admin section, which uses the regular `firebase` JS package.

This is the code I use:

```
const metadata = {
  cacheControl: "public,max-age=31536000,must-revalidate"
  // contentType: "image/jpeg" // THIS IS AUTO INFERRED BY FIREBASE
};


const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`${directory}/${fileName}`);
const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file,metadata);

uploadTask.on("state_changed",
  function progress() {...},
  function error() {...},
  function complete() {...}
);
```

And this is what I get on Firebase storage console: a nice preview with links and a download token. Even though the `cacheControl` metadata is not displayed, it was set, 'cause it's visible when I visit the image's URL on my browser.

[image]

Now I'm writing an `admin` script to upload some images that I have on my local machine to my Firebase storage.

This is the code:

```
async function uploadImage() {

  admin.storage().bucket().upload(
    `./temp/${imageLocation}`,       // THIS IS MY LOCAL PATH
    { 
      destination: imageLocation,    // THIS IS THE PATH FOR THE STORAGE
    }
  );
  console.log(`Uploaded: ${imageLocation}`);
}
```

Everything works fine, the file was indeed uploaded, but this is what I get on Firebase storage console:

[image]

**QUESTION**

How can I use the `firebase-admin` in a way that I get the same consistent result as when I'm uploading an image using the `firebase` JS package on the browser?

Can I use the regular `firebase` package in my NodeJs admin script? I think I would have to authenticate as an `admin` user before making the `firebase.storage().ref().put()` request, since all storage paths are protected with `allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;`.

Comment: Lack of preview for files uploaded with a backend SDK is a known issue with the Firebase console.  If you don't like this behavior, contact Firebase support directly, as there is no documented solution.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add uuidv4 package:

```
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4')

bucket.upload('cat.png', {
    destination: 'cat.png',
    metadata: {
        metadata: {
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid(),
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: Thans, Methkal. I've also written an answer, would you take a look at it? I've noticed that the `firebase` JS SDK also adds a "weird" `contentDisposition` header. What does it do?  I'm also adding it just in case. Also, is it ok to use the `import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";` instead of `uuidv4` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'm dealing with this:

When you upload something to the storage using the `firebase` JS SDK, it automatically adds some metadata along with it.

AFAIK, it adds two pieces of metadata:

```
const metadataObject = {
  contentDisposition: `inline; filename*=utf-8''${fileName}`  // THIS IS "REGULAR METADATA"
  metadata: {
    firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: downloadToken  // THIS IS "CUSTOM METADATA"
  }
}
```

The `downloadToken` is just a unique key generated with `uuid()`. As we can see from the snippet below from the Cloud Console (not the `firebase` console, because you can't see the metadata from there).

[image]

So you need to mimic that behavior when you are uploading an image with the `firebase-admin` package.

Here is how you can do it:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

// INITIALIZE THE ADMIN WITH YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT CREDENTIALS

admin.initializeApp({...});

/* ########################### */ 
/* #### GENERATE METADATA #### */
/* ########################### */ 

function generateMetadataObject(fileName: string) {
  const downloadToken = uuid();
  const metadataObject = {
    contentType: `image/jpeg`,  // contentType IS OPTIONAL CAUSE IT WILL BE AUTO-INFERRED
    cacheControl: `public,max-age=31536000,must-revalidate`,  // YOU CAN ALSO USE IT TO ADD OTHER METADATA LIKE cacheControl
    contentDisposition: `inline; filename*=utf-8''${fileName}`,
    metadata: {
      firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: downloadToken
    }
  };
  return metadataObject;
}

/* ##################################################### */
/* #### UPLOAD LOCAL IMAGE TO STORAGE WITH METADATA #### */
/* ##################################################### */

async function uploadImage() {

  const imageLocation = "/some/local_folder/someImage.jpg";
  const fileName = "someImage.jpg";

  await admin.storage().bucket().upload(
    imageLocation,   // THIS IS THE LOCAL PATH OF THE FILE
    {
      destination: "some/bucket_folder/someImage.jpg",  // THIS IS THE BUCKET PATH
      metadata: generateMetadataObject(fileName)        // ADD METADATA OBJECT
    }
  );
  console.log("File with metadata was uploaded to bucket..."); 
}
```

Doing like this, you'll get the same behavior and preview on the Firebase console as if you had uploaded the file using the regular `firebase` JS SDK package.